# using Javascript how to display element one by one on click

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

how to display element one by one on click using only Javascript, in my example when I click all elements show at once, but i need only one click - one element. I appreciate if you show the simplest way to do if in order to i can understand how it works

```
$(function() {
    var cars = ["audi", "bmw", "volvo"];
    var x = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <cars.length; i++) {
        x += cars[i] + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = x;
    }
});
```

Comment: "using only Javascript"? Do you mean without jQuery? So why are you using `$`?

Comment: without Jquery during finding elements in array

Comment: can you add example into  jsfiddle.net

Comment: Do you need something like javascript `yield`https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may update your code as follows. At the very beginnig, your are initializing `x` with empty string. Then for each click on button, append an element from array with `new line` tag.

```js
var cars = ["audi", "bmw", "volvo"];
var x = "";
var i = 0;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  if( i < cars.length) {
    x += cars[i++] + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
<button id="btn">Result</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you really helped, i read that immediate function have to deal with such tasks well, but it didn't work when i use it, but your example really nice

Answer (score 0):

```
<html> 
<script>
        var cars = ["audi", "bmw", "volvo"];
        var x = "";
        var count = 0;
          function appendArray(){

        if(count<cars.length){
        x += cars[count]+ "<br>";
            document.getElementById("appendText").innerHTML = x;
            count++;
            }else{
        count = 0;
        document.getElementById("appendText").innerHTML = "";
        }

     }
    </script>


    <p id="appendText"></p>
    <button onclick="appendArray()">Submit</button>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution in vanilla javascript:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var i = 0;

function addCar(i) {
    var cars = ['audi', 'bmw', 'volvo'];
    var paragraph = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

    if (i < cars.length) {
        var newLine = document.createElement('br');
        var newCar = document.createTextNode(cars[i]);
        paragraph.appendChild(newLine);
        paragraph.appendChild(newCar);
    }
}

    
button.addEventListener('click',function(){addCar(i); i++;},false);
```

```html
<p></p>
<button>Click for a New Car</button>
```